# Change source file code before publishing on production site using git

Tags: git, github

I have created one project using node.js and publish using git. As per my logic, I have to change some variable's value in my 'app.js' file (e.g. app environment from 'development' to 'production', static file path, database connection etc.) every time before publish without fail, else problem will occur on production. It's is very hack tic job and need focus while publishing website to production. Is there any option/command in git to do above stuff automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Move those config variable to a config file for ex: `config.js` and use it in your `app.js`.

Basically in `config.js` you can define you variable in a `if...else` condition block as per `development` or `production`.

```
if(inProduction()) {
 // Define production variable
} else {
  // Define developement variable
}
```

NOTE:Define `inProduction` method in config which will return `true` if it's production else return `false`.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Hi @deepak-biswal, I have done same thing as you preferred. But what about static file changes or as per your code, I have to change isProduction() every time before publish.

Comment: static file means? Do you have different files depends on production or development?

Comment: yes deepak. and database connection and image path is also different

Comment: Database connection you can define above config.js file for different for production and development. Ad for image path define which are fixed in config file and then append that path in you files where you are using image.

Comment: for ex: in config - `http://www.yoursite.com/imageDir` and then use it in your image path.